# Should we close msyql connection in wsgi flask deployment?

Tags: flask, flask-mysql

I follow the flask_mysql document but why it does not close the mysql connection. Currently, I deploy flask with apache wsgi, but i do not sure whether we should close the connection for each request ?

I do not close connection in my current code and nothing is error.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route('/')
def users():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('''SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user''')
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    return str(rv)

@app.route('/update_my_row",methods=["PUT"]
def update_my_row():
    conn = mysql.connect
    cur = mysql.cursor()
    ....update ...
    conn.commit()
    ## do we need conn.close() here , and what happen if not.
    return my_response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Can anyone explain me  should i close the connection for each request handler or not ? Thank you.

Comment: cursor close is recommended to free the resources associated with the query.

Comment: what about connection close, i read git resposity, it said that : " What that means is that the extension will manage creating and teardown the connection to MySQL for you while with if you were just using MySQLdb you would have to do it yourself."

Comment: git source : https://github.com/admiralobvious/flask-mysqldb